# d3.js: get tick values outside extent of input domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given a list of values

```
var values = [245, 483, 498, 597, 726, 788, 799, 974];
```

I want to get tick values that "surround" the extent of the `values` domain:

```
// [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
```

Using the following does not work for this intent:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(values));
var ticks = scale.ticks(9);
// [300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900] == ticks
```

That is no surprise since the D3.js reference says:

> The returned tick values are […] guaranteed to be within the extent of
>   the input domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.nice()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_nice):

```
var values = [245, 483, 498, 597, 726, 788, 799, 974];
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(values)).nice();
var ticks = scale.ticks(9);
```